# How do I format this case statement in sql?

Tags: sql, switch-statement, case

Basically, I want to return a `1` if the Field Blue is a `'Y'` and a blank if it is not.  Is this how I should go about this?

```
Case isnull(Blue, 'N') when Blue = 'Y' then 1 else '' end
```

Comment: you can return a `'1'` and `''` otherwise datatype mismatch

Comment: You're right.  I just fixed that.  But otherwise, how does this look? Is it formatted correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do either

```
Case isnull(Blue, 'N') when 'Y' then '1' else '' end
```

or

```
Case when isnull(Blue, 'N') = 'Y' then '1' else '' end
```

see [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your null check is redundant. You only need to test for `'Y'`:

```
Case when Blue = 'Y' then '1' else '' end
```